# Error: type specifier missing, how do I fix this error?

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

The specific error is:

```
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: snackbar] Error 1
chapter3/snackbar/ $ make snackbar
snackbar.c:52:1: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-int]
menu[0].item = "burger";
```

I am a little confused on this error, I have tried many things, perhaps my code is incorrect?
My code is:

```
// Find your total cost at a snackbar

/**
 * Beach Burger Shack has the following 10 items on their menu
 * Burger: $9.5
 * Vegan Burger: $11
 * Hot Dog: $5
 * Cheese Dog: $7
 * Fries: $5
 * Cheese Fries: $6
 * Cold Pressed Juice: $7
 * Cold Brew: $3
 * Water: $2
 * Soda: $2
*/

#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

// Number of menu items
// Adjust this value (10) to number of items input below
#define NUM_ITEMS 10

// Menu items have item name and price
typedef struct
{
    string item;
    float price;
}
menu_item;

// Array of menu items
menu_item menu[NUM_ITEMS] = {
    {"Burger", 9.5},
    {"Vegan Burger", 11},
    {"Hot Dog", 5},
    {"Cheese Dog", 7},
    {"Fries", 5},
    {"Cheese Fries", 6},
    {"Cold Pressed Juice", 7},
    {"Cold Brew", 3},
    {"Water", 2},
    {"Soda", 2},
};

// Add items to menu
void add_items(void);

menu[0].item = "burger";
menu[0].price = 9.50;

menu[1].item = "vegan burger";
menu[1].price = 11;

menu[2].item = "hot dog";
menu[2].price = 5;

menu[3].item = "cheese dog";
menu[3].price = 7;


// Calculate total cost
float get_cost(string item);

int main(void)
{
    add_items();

    printf("\nWelcome to Beach Burger Shack!\n");
    printf("Choose from the following menu to order. Press enter when done.\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        printf("%s: $%.2f\n", menu[i].item, menu[i].price);
    }
    printf("\n");

    float total = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        string item = get_string("Enter a food item: ");
        if (strlen(item) == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }

        total += get_cost(item);
    }

    printf("Your total cost is: $%.2f\n", total);
}

// Add at least the first for items to the menu array
void add_items(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        menu[i].item = get_string("Enter a food item: ");
    }
}

// Search through the menu array to find an item's cost
float get_cost(string item)
{
    // Linear search for item
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(menu[i].item, item) == 0)
        {
           return menu[i].price;
        }
    }
    // Item was not found
    return 0.0;
}
```

Th program prompts the user for a food item, and once the user is done, the enter key is pressed, which exits the loop to prompt the user, and then it prints the total cost. I am getting errors for the add_items array.

Comment: You cannot write `menu[0].item = "burger";` outside of a function

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: See [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) to avoid shooting yourself in the foot. (use ints/longs instead)

Comment: You can't write arbitrary code outside of a function. There's restrictions on what you can do there. If you're used to something like Python, you must change your expectations.

Comment: If you could write code like that outside of a function, there would be no need for a `main` function.  Hey, where did you get `string` from?!  I have some bad news for you there =]

Comment: @Jason This question is tagged as [`cs50`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cs50/info). `string` is a part of the [CS50 library](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/). It is an alias of `char *`, and [`get_string`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_string) performs the bookkeeping required to hide the details.

Comment: @Oka ick... That seems incredibly fragile.  Well, I learned something new today.

Answer (score 3):

While you may perform [declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations) and [initializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization) at [*file scope*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope), you may not perform an [assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment).

Remove

```
menu[0].item = "burger";
menu[0].price = 9.50;

menu[1].item = "vegan burger";
menu[1].price = 11;

menu[2].item = "hot dog";
menu[2].price = 5;

menu[3].item = "cheese dog";
menu[3].price = 7;
```

or otherwise place these expressions inside a function.

Do note that these assignments may be redundant, as `menu` is already being *initialized* with these same values:

```
menu_item menu[NUM_ITEMS] = {
    {"Burger", 9.5},
    {"Vegan Burger", 11},
    {"Hot Dog", 5},
    {"Cheese Dog", 7},
    /* ... */
```